# How can I determine which data is displayed in a React component using an useState array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a menu of buttons and each button opens the same component containing a title and a textarea. However, the content shown in the title and textarea must change based on the choice in the menu.

The data is taken from an API and put into a useState array. So I want to use this data in the called component. Does anyone know how you can determine, based on the button in the menu, which data is called in the new component?

**This is what I have so far:**

**Menu Component:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ScenarioContent from "./ScenarioContent";

const ScenarioMenu = (handleScenario, scenarioChoice) => {
    const [scenarioContent, setScenarioContent] = useState(false);
    const [scenarioList, setScenarioList] = useState([]);

    const setContent = () => {
        if (!scenarioContent) {
            setScenarioContent(true);
        }

        console.log(scenarioContent);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/scenario/')
            const data = await res.json();
            setScenarioList(data);
            console.log(scenarioList);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getButtons = (num) => {
        const newScenarioArr = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            newScenarioArr.push(<button onClick={setContent}>scenario {i}</button>)
        }
        return newScenarioArr;
    }



    return (
        <div className="container-scenarioSelect">
            <div className="btn-group-scenario">
                {
                    getButtons(scenarioList.length)
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                {scenarioContent ? <ScenarioContent /> : ""}
            </div>

        </div >
    )
}

export default ScenarioMenu
```

**And this is the Content component with hardcoded data:**

```
const ScenarioContent = (scenarioTitle, scenarioText) => {
    return (
        <div className="container-scenarioChoice">
            <div>
                <h1>Hamsterwoede!</h1>
                <label className="labels" for="scenario"> Scenario:  </label>
                <textarea className="text-area" type="text" id="scenario" name="scenario" rows="25" cols="80" >Met oplopende Olifantengriepcijfers op de horizon zijn inwoners van Engelse Eiland massaal begonnen met het inslaan van tampons. Deze zouden helpen de Olifantengriep uit de neus te houden en daarmee een infectie te voorkomen. De regering van Engelse Eiland verzoekt haar burgers dringend om te stoppen met hamsteren, en verzekert hen ervan dat de voorraden groot genoeg zijn om iedereen te kunnen bedienen. Over de effectiviteit van het tampongebruik als preventie van de Olifantengriep zijn door experts nog geen uitspraken gedaan. In Digitanzanië beginnen de eerste geluiden al op te gaan om spullen in te slaan. Wat moet de overheid doen?
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-group-scenario">
                <button>Terug</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-group-scenario">
                <button>Sla op</button>
            </div>



        </div>
    )
}

export default ScenarioContent
```

[This is how it looks right now, so the menu is left and the content is in the middle. the content must therefore be adjusted, but in the same component based on the menu choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1yhc.png)

Comment: You can add an id to the button tag and then use it in setScenarioContent and select the content you need from the list according to the id

Answer (score 0):

In your getButtons function, you return buttons and you have this code:

```
newScenarioArr.push(<button onClick={setContent}>scenario {i}</button>)
```

When the button is clicked you have to store which button is clicked so you can pass data related to that button to ScenarioContent. You can pass i to setContent function and store this i in a state. So the code above should change to this:

```
newScenarioArr.push(<button onClick={() => setContent(i)}>scenario {i}</button>)
```

So now you get number of the button called in argument of setContent. You have a state called scenarioContent where you store true and false and the value determines whether you should show ScenarioContent or not. You should add a new state and use it to store the button that is clicked. So:

```
//this is the state where you store the number of button clicked
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(); 

const setContent = (i) => {
    if (!scenarioContent) {
        setScenarioContent(true);
        setButtonClicked(i);
    }
}
```

Now to pass the list you want, your return code should change to something like this:

```
{scenarioContent ? 
   <ScenarioContent 
      scenarioTitle={scenarioList[buttonClicked].title} 
      scenarioText={scenarioList[buttonClicked].text 
   /> 
 : ""}
```

Some other things I think you can change to improve your code:

You can use map function of arrays instead of for loop. This will make your code cleaner. So instead of getButtons function, write this in return statement:

```
//change this and getButtons function
{
   getButtons(scenarioList.length)
}

//to this: 
{
   ScenarioList.map((scenario, index) => (
      <button onClick={() => setContent(index)}>scenario {index}</button>
   )
}

// With this method, you can also use some information from your scenario to render the button
// let's say you want to use scenario's title in as button's title
{
   ScenarioList.map((scenario, index) => (
      <button onClick={() => setContent(index)}>{scenario.title}</button>
   )
}
```

You can also just use one state instead of buttonClicked and scenarioContent. To implement this, you can change your setContent function to this:

```
const setContent = (index) => {
    setScenarioContent(scenarioList[index]);
}
```

In this approach, you use index to write data related to the button in the scenarioContent state directly. Now you can use this state to pass data to ScenarioContent component directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot and I have learnt so many new things. One question, how do I turn the scenarioContent state back to false? Because now it works ones but when I click on another button in the menu it won't work and it stays on the same data.

Comment: Your original code doesn't work like that because in your setContent function, you check value of scenarioContent and you change scenarioContent only if it's value is false. So you should remove that if. Also if you use the codes I wrote in the post as suggestion ( the one with map function and new implementation of setContent), it's gonna work and change the content everytime you click a button. I hope this helps